# How do I find the number value for an attribute?

Tags: attributes

I'm editing existing code on a product page that was made by a third party.  They've got an $ignore on attribute number values that block attributes from displaying on the page.  Instead of trial and error is their something that will show me a list of  attributes and numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Find a Number Of value For An `attribute` use the below code.

```
<?php
  echo "<pre>";
  $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color'); //here, "color" is the attribute_code

  $allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);

  foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
     $myArray[$instance['value']] = $instance['label'];
  }

  print_r($myArray);
  echo count($myArray)-1;
?>
```

when you print Data using `print_r($myArray)` then you find fist value blank for select option so I have subtract `1` form count.

Let me know if you have any query.